# App that optimizes images to set as lockscreen?

Tags: lock-screens, images

How can I resize *any* image I have to 720 x 1280 resolution to set it as a lockscreen for my Xperia T? I tried [Wallpaper Wizardrii](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twistedapps.wallpaperwizardrii) but for some reason I cannot get the app to enlarge small pictures to entirely fit the screen.

I had an Apple phone they there was an app called "lockscreen" that automatically stretched/resized any image to match the screen resolution without any empty vertical or horizontal bars.

Are there any equivalent solutions for Android?

Comment: Please note that questions of the type *Is there an app for X* are off topic here (see our [FAQ] for details).

Comment: I have edited the question to be more about a problem to be solved than about an app to be found.

Answer (score -2):

you can try the **Go Locker**.....

Comment: Would you mind to add a little more information, e.g. at least a link and a short description?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Im sorry, it-s just im new here so i dunno how. and this is the first question that i've answered, well Go locker is an application for android. But I reviewed your question, you said you need an app. automatically resizes any image, you can try to search in google play or play store the app.. 'Photo Resizer' or 'Image shrink'. I hope it can help. sorry

Comment: Hey no problem, at all. There's the *edit* button below your answer to do this. This site is somewhat like a wiki. So it's appreciated to edit, btw. So just hit it and add e.g. the link to the play store + maybe the short description, would be fine.